# Yii 1.1.15? Registration form with salt 512

Tags: php, yii

So i am totally new to this Yii framework. I'm doing this project that needs to allow users to sign up and login, The passwords needs to be encrypted with sha512.

I've looked around at plugins but they all require composer or commandline tool.

I have no idea how to use any of these tools on a webserver where yii in located.

Any help would be grand!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32415-create-login-form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database table let's say "User" and create appropriate columns that you want in your project and use "gii" tool to create user registration and login .
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-gii.html

and use http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=gii for generate code.
Thanks,
Saurabh